# Graph from custom string function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compute-shader

I'm stuck and ask you guys for help. I want to create graph using custom math equations evaluated from string. But let me explain the situation first a little bit.

I'm following some tutorials and in my project I can draw custom animated graphs using math equations.
I use compute shader to boost performance, and I have my functions for each equation in there.

Here's example of one of the effects:

```
float3 Ripple(float u, float v, float t)
{
    float d = sqrt(u * u + v * v);
    float3 p;
    p.x = u;
    p.y = sin(PI * (4.0 * d - t));
    p.y /= 1.0 + 10.0 * d;
    p.z = v;
    return p;
}
```

Example of result:

[[image: example of result1]

UV coordinates are also calculated inside same compute shader again to save performance, since there can be up to one milion points(Cubes) in single graph.

```
RWStructuredBuffer<float3> _Positions;

uint _Resolution;
float _Step, _Time, _TransitionProgress;
bool _AbsoluteY, _InvertY;

float2 GetUV(uint3 id)
{
    return (id.xy + 0.5) * _Step - 1.0;
}

void SetPosition(uint3 id, float3 position)
{
    if (id.x < _Resolution && id.y < _Resolution)
    {
        _Positions[id.x + id.y * _Resolution] = position;
    }
}
```

So what I want to achive is to be able to enter some complex Formula like "`sin(u + 4) - cos(PI * v * abs(u))`" somewhere in UI e.g inside an Input Field. And then transform this formula from string so that it can be calculated inside of compute shader with parameters, that are stored there, namely u and v.

I know that I can get those uv parameters using `ComputeBuffer.getData()`, but then I'd have to make all the calculation on CPU side and send it to ComputeShader which is a big performance hit. But even then Idk how to transform a Formula from string to readable equation...
I mean there are plenty of graphic calculation apps, so it should be possible, right?

I've googled for few days and couldn't find what I was looking for so any help is hugely appreciatet.

Comment: Possible, yes. But not trivial. What you're describing is expression parsing. If all you need is to evaluate standard mathematical formulas, then an existing library such as [MathParser](https://mathparser.org/) might get you there. Or you can roll your own expression parser using something like [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache), but that's a bit of a learning curve. Anyway, that should give you a couple of leads for further searches.

Comment: Thanks, @Plasmadog I will look into that now. Hopefully, it will give me enough of a lift for further work :)

Comment: I've tried the MathParser and it works good, but not I still have an issue with performance. My usual fps for 40.000 points is around 250 when all calculation happens on computeShader side. But when I do my `positionsBuffer.GetData(output)` and then do a for loop where I calculate and assign values for each `output.y` and sand it back using `positionsBuffer.SetData(output)` I get only like 45fps at max for the same amount of points. So idk what to do now... Is there a way to create a new function from string in computeshader at runtime? or I am probably looking in the wrong direction